# Apple FAX printer using ipp-server configuration for faxout does not transmit the phone number

Tags: macos, printing, cups

I am working on a IPP-FAX client.

I am using the ippserver stuff from: https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample.git

I have a small configuration that provides two printers.

However, when I use the fax-job.test from the library, my client receives the phone number:  IPP_DESTINATION_URIS='{destination-uri=tel:4055551212},{destination-uri=ipp://11.22.33.44/ipp/print print-quality=high media=na_letter_8.5x11in}'

As expected.

But: when I use the same ipp-device as a fax from apple's printer menues, the pages are sent, but the destination-uri are not send (not included in the IPP transmission).

I am using the following in the service:

```
[root@Comp ~/Printing/ippsample3]# perl -ne 's/#.*//; print unless /^\s*$/' t2/print/faxout.conf
MAKE "thilo"
MODEL "(GPL Ghostscript)"
DeviceURI ipp://Comp.local/ipp/print
Attr textWithoutLanguage printer-device-id "MFG:XSimulated;MDL:Fax;CMD:URF;URF:W8,SRGB24,CP255,PQ4,RS200-300-600,V1.4;MINSIZE:1x5in;MAXSIZE:8.5x14in;TEST-MARGINS:0 0 0 0;TEST-NO-PNG:1;TEST-NO-PDF:1;TEST-FAX:1;"
Command /root/Printing/ippsample3/hell.sh
ATTR keyword urf-supported "W8","SRGB24","ADOBERGB24-48","DM3","CP255","OFU0","IS1-4-5-7","IFU0","MT1-2-3-7-8-9-10-11-12","OB9","PQ3-4-5","RS300-600","V1.4"
ATTR keyword job-creation-attributes-supported "copies","confirmation-sheet-print","cover-sheet-info","destination-uris","media","media-col","multiple-document-handling","number-of-retries","page-ranges","print-quality","printer-resolution","retry-interval","retry-time-out"
ATTR uriScheme destination-uri-schemes-supported "tel"
ATTR boolean ipp-attribute-fidelity true
ATTR boolean confirmation-sheet-print-default false
ATTR integer number-of-retries-default 1
ATTR integer retry-interval-default 15
ATTR keyword cover-sheet-info-supported "date-time","from-name","subject","to-name","message"
ATTR no-value cover-sheet-info-default
ATTR rangeOfInteger number-of-retries-supported 0-1
ATTR rangeOfInteger retry-interval-supported 15-60
ATTR uri printer-icons "http://Comp.local:8632/icons/fax.png","http://Comp.local:8632/icons/large/fax.png"
ATTR uri printer-more-info "http://Comp.local:8632/"
ATTR uri printer-supply-info-uri "http://Comp.local:8632/"
ATTR uri printer-uuid "urn:uuid:3f63711e-bcc3-3570-707e-cc14008da4b6"
ATTR keyword uri-authentication-supported "none","none"
ATTR keyword uri-security-supported "tls","tls"
ATTR uri printer-geo-location "geo:37.33182,122.03118"
ATTR uri device-uri "urf:///1+1"
```

from reading http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-ippfaxout10-20140618-5100.15.pdf . I understand that the destination-uris would be mandatory in the job descriptor.

I either fail to teach the IPP-server to require if from the client, or I fail to configure the client correctly.

From: https://github.com/michaelrsweet/libcups/raw/f06f42779f98073e2ba782a7a73ebf54636b60d0/examples/fax-job.test

```
      GROUP job-attributes-tag
        ATTR collection destination-uris {
                MEMBER uri destination-uri tel:4055551212
        },{
                MEMBER uri destination-uri ipp://11.22.33.44/ipp/print
                MEMBER enum print-quality 5
                MEMBER keyword media na_letter_8.5x11in
        }
```

Any hints how the service should be configured to make apple printer also send this scheme?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that once the faxout uri is changed in the server sources to use '/ipp/faxout' instead of the (I think also standard compliant) /ipp/print/faxout, Apple is sending the destination-uri
and the script gets the environment variable: `IPP_DESTINATION_URIS='{destination-uri=tel:1234567890123456}`

as expected.

Comment: see https://github.com/thilo-hub/IPPFritzFax/blob/main/README.md for a full IPP fax servr